# Why aren't emails being sent?

Tags: 7, emails

I know this question was asked so many times but I read all the answers and I didn't find any solution working for me, so I'm looking for help. I have done the following to try resolve it:

1. Checked if the site address is set up properly
2. Downloaded the SMTP module

   - Configured the module to my Gmail account
   - I was getting the unable to send email error here unless I checked the "Send mail by queue box (I am not sure what this does, but the error message disappeared.)
   - When I send a test email to my Gmail address I'm not getting it (I checked spam and it's not there)
3. I have then moved on and downloaded the phpmailer library and extracted it into my sites/all/libraries folder (I even tried putting it in the smtp folder as I read about that somewhere) but still not working

   - I configured the phpmailer with my smtp module and when I tried to send a test email from phpmailer I'm not receiving that either.
4. I checked emails are sent when a user registers or forgets the password, and emails aren't sent in those cases either. Drupal is not sending out emails.
5. I then moved on to check my logs and all the attempts are in red:

[image]

I am new to Drupal; I am not sure what they mean.

Is there anything else I can try?

This is just a test site so I have it on my localhost.

When I click on the error this is the information that is showing:

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this but it says I need to be an administrator to see this option. I don't understand how I am not the administrator.

Comment: It would be wise to blank your email adress in the screenshot. perhaps only mention the error message.

Comment: I am not very familliar with this module but here are a few suggestions -  What happens when you enable debugging at Admin - Configuration - SMTP Authentication Support (admin/config/system/smtp)? Do you see any useful responses from the server? In the README of the module it says you don't need to install the php library anymore as it is included in the module. Do you seen any error at the status page at admin/reports/status?

Comment: Have you  checked if you can send email from the CLI (using [Unix mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(Unix)) or some similar tool)?

Comment: Did you enable SSL in Smpt config?

Comment: Yes I enabled the ssl in config. If I remove the phpmail library will that make any difference? The only thing the status says is that I have to update Drupal core? Could this be the reason for it? However, the email was never working even before there was an update.

Comment: If you click on the "Error sending email" link from your screenshot, do you get more information?

Comment: @user3353335: There are a lot of things that can cause this problem. I definitely recommend trying to send mail from the command line like Free Radical suggested. Is the Drupal site running on a Windows, Mac, or Linux machine?

Comment: I have added a picture of the message that shows when I click on the error. I am running Drupal on Windows. How do I go about trying to send an email from a command line?

Comment: Follow @FreeRadical advice and try to sent email from the system console. When Drupal complains about sending mial usualy it's the server who is not able to send the email. You should first make sure system is able to send mails, then check Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. How do I send an email from the system console though?